# Долгий systemctl автокомплит

Tags: bash, autocomplete, systemd

При попытке systemctl start|stop|status tab tab - очень долго ищет подходящие варианты. Как можно исправить или в чём проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина вроде как кроется в вызове процедурами завершения `systemctl` столько раз, сколько юнитов `systemd` существует на данный момент, - как-то так. Теоретически следующий патч `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/systemctl` должен исправить положение:

```
22c22
<         systemctl $mode --full --no-legend "$@"
---
>         systemctl $mode --full --no-legend --no-pager "$@"
44a45,48
> 
> #
> # UHU PATCH Tue Mar 14 18:50:31 CET 2017 {
> #
46,49c50,53
<             <(__systemctl $mode show --property "$property" -- "${units[@]}")
<         for ((i=0; $i < ${#units[*]}; i++)); do
<                 if [[ "${props[i]}" = "$property=$value" ]]; then
<                         echo " ${units[i]}"
---
>             <(__systemctl $mode show --property Names,"$property" -- \*)
>         for ((i=0; $i < ${#props[*]}; i=i+2)); do
>                 if [[ "${props[i+1]}" = "$property=$value" ]]; then
>                         echo " ${props[i]#Names=}"
51a56,59
> #
> # } UHU PATCH Tue Mar 14 18:50:31 CET 2017
> #
>
```

На практике прирост в производительности незначительный, так что остается уповать на то, что этот уже годовалый (а может и более) баг пофиксят в ближайшее время.